# Use N threads to process list then time out if service time is larger than T

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to using Java and I'm trying to learn threading, so it'd be helpful to get some pointers on this. I don't understand much about using threads, so a for-dummies type of explanation would also help a lot.

I'm working on a project where I have a function foo, and a List of strings which I would like to pass through foo. If the processing time for `foo(S)` goes over `T` milliseconds, I will stop processing `foo(S)`, and then I would move on to `foo(S+1)`. I have a large dataset of strings and they can take too long so I tried using threading and termination to speed things up, but I'm not sure how to terminate if processing takes too long. This is more or less what `foo` does:

```
public static foo(String s){
// use a while loop to manipulate string
// return some integer 
}
```

After some research, I found out that *ExecutorService* would be a good approach, and this is the structure of what I have so far:

```
public static void process(List<String> l, int n) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
    for (final String s: l) {
       executor.submit(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               System.out.println(foo(s));
               //interrupt this process if foo(s) takes >T
           }
       });
   }

executor.shutdown();     
}
```

However, if I run my code without on a small set of strings, it does not terminate nor print anything at all and I am unsure why. Is it stuck inside the for loop in foo? How do I fix that? Can I add a sleep(T) between threads to interrupt a thread that is taking too long? thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to interrupt and terminate a thread already?

Comment: I do not, hoping I would get some help with that!

Comment: In your example `S` is a string from the list, right? And what you want do is basically for-each string in your list transform the string by `foo` and cancel transformations that take too long? The result would be the list with all strings transformed?

Comment: yes, precisely!

Comment: You haven't responded in any way yet. Feel free to ask if there is anything still unclear.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really possible to cancel a task exactly after a specific time. Canceling a task at a specific time (canceling in a sense that the task terminates immediately) would be dangerous, because it could leave data in an inconsistent state, without having the chance to "clear things up".

Therefore, we have interrupts to do a similar thing. You interrupt a task (or a thread), which is basically a notification for the task e.g. to stop its execution *by itself*. In this way, the task is able to terminate in a controlled manner and leave data in a consistent state.

In your example, it would work like so: Every processing of a string in your list would be a task. You have two ways to implement the timeout-mechanism: The task is canceled externally (using interrupts) or it cancels itself. When the task cancels itself, it periodically checks if it is running longer than a timeout, while processing the string. If the timeout is exceeded, the initial value is the result, otherwise the processed string.

In Java it would be something like this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

class Main {
    
    static class ProcessTask implements Callable<String> {
        final String initialValue;
        final long timeout;
        ProcessTask(String initialValue, long timeout) {
            this.initialValue = initialValue;
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            long complexity = (long) (Math.random() * 1_000_000L);
            long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            for (long i = 0; i < complexity; ++i) {
                Math.sqrt(Math.log(i));
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime > timeout) {
                    return initialValue;
                }
            }
            return "new";
        }
    }
    

    static void process(List<String> initialList, int parallelism, int timeout) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism);
        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        initialList.forEach(s -> {
            futures.add(executor.submit(new ProcessTask(s, timeout)));
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < initialList.size(); ++i) {
            try {
                initialList.set(i, futures.get(i).get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000; ++i) {
            myList.add("old");
        }
        process(myList, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 10);
        myList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This is a very explicit way of doing it, but you've asked for it. There are definitely ways of doing that less wordy. If you are unsure about any class here, just do a little bit of research. There is nothing crazy I've used.

What you should see is a mix of `old`s and `new`s in the output, where `new` just indicates that the processing was finished and `old` that the timeout was exceeded and the corresponding task was stopped. If you see something else, play around with the `timeout` parameter of `process`.

The most important part for you to look at is the `call` method. There is the mechanism that stops a task after a timeout by periodically checking the runtime. You need place those checks at correct places in your processing algorithm to stop the task.